# How do I generate 500 random orders, with items in the order uniform distribution of (1,5) in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a mysql database which I have already connected to. It has a bunch of items with a certain ID for each item. I need to generate 500 random orders, where each order includes a random number of items sampled from a uniform distribution with parameters (1, 5).

I'm having trouble starting, but this is all i have.

```
x = numpy.random.uniform( low = 1, high = 5, size = 500 )
```

Comment: This is giving me a list with 500 numbers from range 1-5, but they have a bunch of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

if you want ints you need randint

```
numpy.random.randint(1,6,size=500)
```